# Add image banner on top of fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to push an image banner on top of a page using JS. The problem I am facing is with fixed navigation bar. My goal is to put the navigation bar under the image banner but when you scroll down below the image banner, the navigation banner should be fixed again on top of the page.

Here is HTML code (the div .top-banner could be also placed outside of wrapper if it is easier/better)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-banner">
    <img src="https://b2b.bbanner.co.uk/Content/images/banner.jpg" />
  </div>
  <nav id="nav">
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
  </nav>
  <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0 0 0 133px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 51px;
    display: table;
    min-width: 762px;
}

.top-banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

JSFIELD: https://jsfiddle.net/3nu16e59/

Any help how to solve this issue with css? thank you

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript solution is to use `scrollTop` to detect how far the user has scrolled, and toggle a class that applies `position: fixed`

```js
var banner = document.getElementById('banner'),
 threshold = banner.offsetTop + banner.clientHeight,
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
  var scrolled = document.body.scrollTop;
  if (scrolled >= threshold) {
   nav.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
   nav.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
})
```

```css
#nav {
    padding: 0;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0 0 0 133px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    height: 51px;
    font-size: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    display: table;
    min-width: 762px;
}
#nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.top-banner img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-banner" id="banner">
  <img src="https://b2b.bbanner.co.uk/Content/images/banner.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="nav">
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
  </nav>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  <p>Scrolling</p>
  
  
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // hide .navbar first
    $("#nav").hide();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#nav').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#navr').fadeOut();
            }
        });


    });

});
  }(jQuery));
```

Add this jquery and try. You can embed this within script tag

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for css solution, than just change the navigation position property from fixed to sticky:

```css
#nav {
    padding: 0;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0 0 0 133px;
    position: sticky;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 51px;
    font-size: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    display: table;
    min-width: 762px;
}

.top-banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-banner">
    <img src="https://b2b.bbanner.co.uk/Content/images/banner.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="nav">
        <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </nav>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
    <p>Scrolling</p>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nu16e59/12/).

Please note, at this time (Feb 2017), the sticky position is not supported by Edge, or Android browser, check the [compatibility table here](http://caniuse.com/css-sticky/embed/).